# If $f^{-1}$ has nowhere zero derivative, then $f$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, functions

I think you need to apply theorem 5 from chapter 12 of Spivaks calculus, but not sure how to.
If someone could please help me. The question is:

> Suppose $f$ is a one-one function and the inverse of $f$ has a derivative which is nowhere zero. Prove that $f$ is differentiable.

Chapter 12, Theorem 5:

> Let $f$ be a continuous one-one function defined on an interval, and suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $f^{-1}(b)$, with derivative $f'(f^{-1}(b))\neq 0$. Then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $b$, and $$(f^{-1})'(b) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(b))}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We make the following observations:

1. If $f$ is one-to-one then $f^{-1}$ is one-to-one.
2. If $f^{-1}$ is one-to-one then $f^{-1}$ has an inverse, and $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$.

Now this is a simple case of applying Theorem 5 to the function $f^{-1}$.

Comment: To apply Theorem 5 directly you need continuity of $f^{-1}$, and this follows from differentiability.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I thought about making that remark, then figured that the OP should do at least that much :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and editing my question.

Comment: If you liked this answer please consider upvoting and/or accepting it: see http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask to learn how the upvoting/accepting system works.

Comment: @proximal: Users with less than 15 reputation points cannot vote.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Awwwww. Guess I'll just take home some self-satisfaction today.